# Most effective way (for body) in pull up exercise

Tags: pull-ups

Does the most effective way (for body) in pull up exercise starts with stretched hands with almost locked elbows and ends when your chest touch the bar? What part of your chest should touch the bar?

Comment: Do you mean effective or efficient (economic)? Since for the former, the question always have to be *to what goal*?